# Is there a way to log username and client IP address in SonarQube 5.x access.log?

Tags: logging, ldap, sonarqube, sonarqube5.1, sonarqube-ops

The current access logs in the logs directory, does not contain the username. The sonar.properties configuration file do not seem to provide a way to customize the log format in a way to log the username. Is there any way to match the logged username in each access.log entry?

Comment: Hi G.Ann, could you explain why a -1 on this? thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I take for good Simon's answer in the comment:

"I confirm that it's not possible to log username in access.log. It will be fixed in versions 6.x : jira.sonarsource.com/browse/SONAR-7581"  --  Simon Brandhof - SonarSource

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe this has anything to do with LDAP or the SonarQube LDAP plugin in particular. For example, if you do a fresh install SonarQube and login as admin user (no LDAP is involved here), the username will not be recorded in the access log. My hunch is that the username field in the access log would be there if SonarQube relied on the standard HTTP authorization header. If you inspect the traffic between the browser and the SonarQube server during login, you will see that the credentials are passed in a form and the server will set a cookie with a session ID and an authentication token. Both of these are opaque, don't carry the username and the logger in SonarQube does not do any extra effort log this (see also this [source file](https://github.com/SonarSource/sonarqube/blob/1974edc40b343aaf0a0e6028af4fca7f8153dbd5/server/sonar-server/src/main/java/org/sonar/server/app/TomcatAccessLog.java)).

I agree that it would be nice to have the username logged.

Comment: I confirm that it's not possible to log username in access.log. It will be fixed in versions 6.x : https://jira.sonarsource.com/browse/SONAR-7581